# Using _ViewImports.cshtml File

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I made this _ViewImports.cshtml File, which inside refers to **Models** namespace in my Models folder. 
[image: ViewImports.cshtml]

Now in my Index.cshtml page when I want to remove "@using Razor.Models.Products " I encounter an error
[image: Error Message]

now I'm sure I did it right since when I use the  "@ using expression" , it says its redundant:
[image: redundant]

what could be the problem?